# SELECTing everything that has changed since the last SELECT

Tags: sql-server

Leaving aside probably [better](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) [ways](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280462%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to get "table diffs" from an SQL server - suppose I have a table with an `UpdTime` column of type `datetime`, which is set and updated using `getdate()` on every insert and update, like so:

```
UPDATE mytable SET Updtime=getdate(), ... WHERE ...
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (getdate(),...)
```

After an initial

```
SELECT getdate() AS Now, ... FROM mytable WITH(readcommitted,rowlock)
```

where I once read all rows and store the value of `Now` in a variable `lastNow`, I then continue to do periodical

```
SELECT getdate() AS Now, ... FROM mytable WITH(readcommitted,rowlock) WHERE UpdTime >= lastNow;
```

calls, always storing the new `Now` into my `lastNow` variable.

Can I be sure to never miss a change (except DELETEs, obviously)? Or is this dependent on some settings?

Btw, seeing a change twice doesn't bother me, only missing a change would.

**Edit** I just added `WITH(readcommitted,rowlock)` to the `SELECT` statements above, because that's how the old statements, to which I want to add the "diff" feature, look like.

Comment: Is everything running under the default isolation levels (or higher) and with no hints? And no snapshot isolation?

Comment: How do you set `UpdTime` on `UPDATE`?

Comment: @MartinSmith I added update and insert statements to the question

Comment: Would it not be better to use a `rowversion` column?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I guess that's what I'm gonna do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getdate()` is a [runtime constant function](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2010/04/23/conor-vs-runtime-constant-functions.aspx) meaning it is evaluated once and the same value is used throughout the statement.

It would certainly be possible at default `readcommitted` level for an `UPDATE` statement to begin and evaluate `GETDATE()` then for a `SELECT` statement to begin and get a later `GETDATE()` value before the `UPDATE` has finished updating all rows.

If the `SELECT` is locating the rows in a different order than the `UPDATE`s (perhaps the two use different index access methods) or the `UPDATE` has a blocking operator in the plan (e.g. for halloween protection) then the `SELECT` could read rows before they have yet been updated. These rows would not then be read at the next request as the eventual `Updtime` they will receive is less than the `lastNow` value.

If the `UPDATE` plan was to contain a blocking operator maybe this would even be possible under `serializable`.

Comment: Very informative, thanks. I guess I should use `rowversion`, as suggested by Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: @EugeneBeresovksy - `rowversion` might still have the same problem at `readcommitted`. If the `UPDATE` affects `R1` and `R2` in that order and the `SELECT` reads the before version of `R1` and the after version of `R2` then you won't see the change to `R1` as the value that got is `< MAX(timestamp)`

Comment: Gotcha. Will have to think a bit more about it. One (cumbersome) way could be to detect gaps in the values of `rowversion` and use the lowest missing value in the next `SELECT`. (As I don't mind duplicates).

Comment: I'm surprised the [official documentation of GETDATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx) is not saying anything on it being a *runtime constant function*.

Comment: @EugeneBeresovksy - It is briefly mentioned at the bottom of [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190642(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you question is, because "Can I be sure to never miss a change (except DELETEs, obviously)? Or is this dependent on some (transactional?) settings?" seems to imply that if a change is made (and then rolled back) you want to see it? I'm not sure if you want to see if an attempted change has been made?

You will not see the change unless your select contains the 'read dirty' hint. If it does, you will see all committed changes and all uncomitted changes, but not those rolled back, as they no longer exist. With read dirty you will get both original and uncommitted (updated) rows returned.

The other aspect of using getdate() is that it is granular down to 1000th sec, which used to be ok, but with modern parallel processors it is quite possible to get mutiple updates with the same GetDate() value.